# Discord forward images

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I'm trying to make a bot that forwards everything from a channel to another channel using `discord.py`. Messages forward with no issue, but when it comes to images, they don't get forwarded. Here is a little example:

Input:
[image: Input]

Output:
[image: Output]

Here is the code I've written so far:

```
if message.channel.id == input_channel_id:
    channel = client.get_channel(output_channel_id)
    await channel.send(message.content)
```

Thank you!

Edit: It only happens to images from https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments. For example, image links from https://tradingview.com work fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Message.attachments](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html?highlight=channel#discord.Message.attachments) you might wanna check if the message has an attachment and then send it

Comment: Yeah, message.attachments solved the issue. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You should check if images have a different input_channel_id. What are you using to access the web?